# Декомпиляция sql clr

Tags: .net, sql-server

Можно ли как-нибудь достать clr сборку, которая была развёрнута на sql server и декомпилировать Ее? Если щёлкнуть по сборке, то можно получить скрипт, где содержится бинарный код. Можно ли из него получить dll?

Comment: Так а почему не попробуете открыть каким нибудь ILSpy или JustDecompiler?

Comment: Проблема в том, что физической сборки у меня нету. Есть какой-то двоичный код в скрипте развертывания сборки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Если щёлкнуть по сборке, то можно получить скрипт, где содержится
>   бинарный код. Можно ли из него получить dll?

Этот бинарный код и есть байты .dll, загруженной в SqlServer. Достаточно их просто выгрузить в файл, после чего можно пробовать применять инструменты декомпиляции.

Найдите интересующую сборку в *sys.assembly_files*:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM sys.assembly_files;
```

Содержимое сборки доступно в *content*:

```sql
SELECT content
FROM sys.assembly_files
WHERE name = N'AssemblyName';
```

Выгрузить содержимое в файл можно, например, с помощью утилиты **bcp** (подробнее о ней в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility)):

```text
bcp "SELECT content FROM sys.assembly_files WHERE name = N'AssemblyName'" queryout "AssemblyName.dll" -S instanceName -d dbName -T
```

(параметры скорректируйте под соответствующие инстанс/БД/логин/пароль).

bcp в интерактивном режиме спросит параметры сохранения

```
Enter the file storage type of field content [varbinary(max)]:
Enter prefix-length of field content [8]: 0 <---- тут 0
Enter length of field content [0]:
Enter field terminator [none]:

Do you want to save this format information in a file? [Y/n] n <---- а тут - "нет"
```

Длину префикса укажите равной *0*, сохранение формата в файл - *n* (нет), остальное оставьте по умолчанию (просто жмите <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: А если bcp нет под рукой? Сохранить все в файл и парсить ручками, заполняя байтовый массив или 1 строчкой, как-то можно?

Comment: @iluxa1810, я бы наверное простую утилиту-клиента на C# (или на PowerShell) написал, что то типа `using (var dr = new SqlCommand("SELECT content FROM ...", conn).ExecuteReader()) { if (dr.Read()) { dr.GetStream(0).CopyTo(fileStream); }}`. Ещё вариант - если в БД есть таблица типа FileTable - создать в ней запись с содержимым assembly, а потом скопировать файл через файловую систему.

Comment: Т.е в C# нету решения, что бы если скопирую бинарную последовательность в текстовый файл из него получить сборку?

Comment: @iluxa1810, всмысле скопировать сгенерированное `0x4D5A9000...` в текстовый файл и преобразовать? В принципе можно, если есть необходимость. Что-то типа `File.WriteAllBytes("Assembly.dll", StringToByteArray(File.ReadAllLines("AssemblyHex.txt")[0]));` (функцию _StringToByteArray_ взять, например, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321404/2523686)). Только hex-строку в файл без `0x` копировать тогда (либо в коде отрезать).